# Ramsauer-Townsend effect one dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, scattering

I am trying to learn basic one dimensional quantum mechanical scattering. The approach used is studying the stationary wave with a square potential barrier with $V_0$ as the positive potential and $L$ as the length of the barrier.

My textbook says that for certain energies, namely $E = -V_0 + \frac{n^2 \hbar^2 \pi^2}{2mL^2}$ for n = 1, 2, 3... the probability for transmission is 1. It says this effect is due to interference. When I try to draw this I only get a contructive interference on the reflective wave, which does not explain this phenomenon to me. I would appreciate if anyone could explain this effect since the explanation in the book is a bit slim and it is hard to find such an easy example elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. What I did wrong when drawing my picture was to make a phase shift at both boundaries of the square potential. There is supposed to only be a phase shift at one of the boundaries. This is analog to an electromagnetic wave where phase shift or not is dependent on whether the electric permitivity is increasing or decreasing in the boundary.